# How can I loop radio button sets in Angular

Tags: angular

Here how can I take response to `res.response1`, `res.response2` respectively in each loop

```html
<div *ngFor="let qandoi of qando;   let id=index" class="form-group">

   <h6>{{qandoi.question}}</h6>
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{id}}+1" id="{{id}}+100" value={{qandoi. option1}} [( ngModel )]="res.response1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="{{id}}+100">
         {{ qandoi  .option1}}
      </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please describe your issue more. What do you want to achieve? What is expected and actual output?

Comment: Hi,i have an array of objects ,each object contains 1question and 5 options(radio buttons)..i want to display them in webpage and record response for each set,Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ngFor loop on the element and use the index in whichever way you want.

For instance, with an array named 'test' that contains three elements, this piece of code:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of test; let i = index" class="element--{{i}}"> </div>
```

Computes to these three divs:

```
<div class="element--0"> </div>
<div class="element--1"> </div>
<div class="element--2"> </div>
```

Comment: Hi,i have an array of objects ,each object contains 1question and 5 options(radio buttons)..i want to display them in webpage and record response for each set,Thanks for helping out :)